# TypeError: connectDb is not a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to express and node while I connecting mongodb from mongoose to localhost I get an error like  `TypeError: connectDb is not a function?`

src/models/index

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const User = require("./user");
const Message = require("./message");

const connectDb = () =>
  mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const models = { User, Message };

exports = { connectDb };
module.exports = models;
```

src/index

```
// .... Some code here

const { connectDb } = require("./models");

// .... Some code here

connectDb()
  .then(async () => {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT);
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exports = { connectDb };
```

this statement is not correct. Its not exporting the `connectDb` function.

if you want to use `exports` keyword to export `connectDb` function, you have to do it as

```
exports.connectDb = () => mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

or simply

```
exports.connectDb = connectDb;
```

If you want to export multiple things, you can add multiple properties to `exports` object

to export models, you can do

```
exports.models = models;
```

Now this file will export an object that has two properties on it, `connectDb` and `models`

Another way to export multiple things is

```
module.exports = {
    connectDb,
    models
};
```

this will also export an object containing two properties, `connectDb` and `models`

Comment: I believe he actually wants to export `models` at first level tho

Answer (score 2):

You are actually doing a weird thing. `exports` variable is set to point to `module.exports`, so when u change its reference by doing `exports = { connectDb }` you are actually breaking that variable's reference, so it's not exporting anything. Next thing u do is exporting ur models, which is correct, but your connectDb is actually not being exported, so you can not use it in your second file. I guess you want to export both, so actually there are some ways to achieve that. Here you have two valid options, first one using the spread operator with `module.exports` and second one using `exports` and not changing its reference but it's properties, so it keeps working correctly:

```
module.exports  = {
  ...models,
  connectDb
}
```

```
exports.connectDb = connectDb
exports.User = User
exports.Message = Message
```